# Mysql Date Comparison with IN Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql query

I have the following Queries

```
SELECT * FROM articles where `id` =1 AND `datatime` > ='datetime1';
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM articles where `id` =2 AND `datatime` > ='datetime2';
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM articles where `id` =3 AND `datatime` > ='datetime3';
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM articles where `id` =4 AND `datatime` > ='datetime4';
```

Which is working fine

Now the problem is that if there is bigger list, maybe more than 10000, then how do I handle this query.
Is there is any other way to do this query?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `union`ing, you should do this in one query.

```
SELECT * FROM articles where 
(`id` =1 AND `datatime` > ='datetime1')
or
(`id` =2 AND `datatime` > ='datetime2')
or
(`id` =3 AND `datatime` > ='datetime3')
or
(`id` =4 AND `datatime` > ='datetime4');
```

You can also do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM articles where 
(id, `datatime`) IN (SELECT 1, 'datetime1'
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2, 'datetime2'
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT 3, 'datetime3'
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT 4, 'datetime4'
                    );
```

If the datatime value is always the same, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM articles where 
id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
and datatime = 'datetime_value';
```

If your list of values gets really big, it's best to put those values in a table first and join it.

```
SELECT * FROM articles a
INNER JOIN your_values_table yvt ON a.id = yvt.id AND a.datatime = yvt.datatime;
```